# how can I carry my element into the event handler function?

Tags: javascript

I am building a tic-tac-toe game.

When the board is loaded, I create event listeners for all of the board's boxes. It will listen to a click, it will then call the placePiece function.

In the placePiece function, how can I target the right box? Can I use 'this'?

I first need to check if the box has already been filled or not. If it isn't, then depending on whether currentPlayer is player1 or player2, it will either fill in a x or 0.

Here is my code:

```
// Add programming, so that when the player clicks the start button the start screen disappears, the board appears, and the game begins.
function loadBoard() {
    document.body.innerHTML = originalHTML;

    player1 = new Player(player1);
    player2 = new Player(player2);

    var startingPlayerNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    console.log(startingPlayerNum);

    if(startingPlayerNum === 1){
        player1.currentPlayer = true;
        currentPlayer = player1;
    } else {
        player2.currentPlayer === true;
        currentPlayer = player2
    }

    //Add clickhandlers for boxes
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var a2 = document.getElementById('a2').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a3').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var b1 = document.getElementById('b1').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var b2 = document.getElementById('b2').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var b3 = document.getElementById('b3').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var c1 = document.getElementById('c1').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var c2 = document.getElementById('c2').addEventListener("click", placePiece);
    var c3 = document.getElementById('c3').addEventListener("click", placePiece);

    currentPlayerFlag()
};
```

// Add the game play following these rules.
        // Play alternates between X and O.

```
    // The current player is indicated at the top of the page -- the box with the symbol O or X is highlighted for the current player. 
function currentPlayerFlag() {
    if(currentPlayer === player1){
        document.getElementById('player1').classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById('player2').className = "players";
    }
    if(currentPlayer === player2){
        document.getElementById('player2').classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById('player1').className = "players";
    }
};


// When the current player mouses over an empty square on the board, it's symbol the X or O should appear on the square.
    // You can do this using the x.svg or o.svg graphics (hint use JavaScript to set the background-image property for that box.) 
function placePiece() {


    // Players can only click on empty squares. When the player clicks on an empty square, attach the class box-filled-1 (for O) or box-filled-2 (for X) to the square.

    //How do I select the right tile?
    if(//SPACE IS NOT EMPTY ?) {
        if(currentPlayer === player1){

            player1.currentPlayer = false;
            player2.currentPlayer = true;
            currentPlayer = player2;
        }
        if(currentPlayer === player2){

            player2.currentPlayer = false;
            player1.currentPlayer = true;
            currentPlayer = player1;
        }

        gameState();
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you save the return value of `addEventListener` into variables?

Comment: *"how can I target the right box? Can I use 'this'?"* - Yes. Have you tried that?

Comment: Probably because I'm a moron, @Andrew, I've fixed that.

@nnnnnn, I've tried it with my mouseOver function:

`function mouseOver() {
 // Do this using the x.svg or o.svg graphics 
 if(currentPlayer === player1){
  this.style.backgroundImage = "url(../tic-tac-toe-v3/img/o.svg)";
 } else {
  this.style.backgroundImage = "url(../tic-tac-toe-v3/img/x.svg)";
 }
};`

with this eventListener: 

`document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);`

Comment: oh I can see it's actually working with `this`, it's just not finding the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
var a1 = document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener("click", function() {placePiece(this)});
```

and adjust `placePiece` accordingly:

```
function placePiece(x) {
    ...
```